# Does Vanu Sovereignty's weapons experience no bullet drop?

Tags: planetside-2

I'm trying to choose between the New Conglomerate and Vanu Sovereignty for a new faction I want to play. I'm currently leaning towards the Vanu Sovereignty because I have heard that their weapons don't experience bullet drop because they fire plasma.

So: Do all Vanu Sovereignty weapons including rocket launchers have no bullet drop? Or is it just for a few sniper rifles?

Comment: Bullet drop isn't that big of a deal in the game. What you really want to look at is Weapon Damage falloff, recoil & accuracy. Take a look at https://ps2model-axiom.rhcloud.com/#dps/la/1/24/22/7173 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCVUNGYP2Gw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few of the Vanu Sovereignty's weapons **do** have bullet drop:

- The S1 (The Heavy Assault's default dumbfire rocket launcher)
- The Hades and Nemesis rocket launchers (when not locked on)
- The bolt-action sniper rifles (XM98, Parallax, Ghost, and V10)

All of the remaining VS-specific weapons have no bullet drop. Arguably, sniper rifles and dumbfire rocket launchers are the only two types of weapon where lack of bullet drop would really be an advantage, but it does make shooting enemies at extreme range a wee bit easier.

(NB: I mostly play Medic/Engineer, so I'm not 100% sure those are the only sniper rifles that have bullet drop. However, I'm sure there are at least a few that do.)

Comment: It can be summarized as: All bolt action snipers have bullet drop as do all rocket launchers (not counting the Lancer which doesn't have bullet drop because it's not a "rocket" launcher). The lock-on rocket launchers do have bullet drop when fired in dumbfire mode.